# "pixie" ears and "pixie" features

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Given **ONLY** this sentence in the environment where design editing is related.

> Would you take away the **pixie** ears and maybe he(***his?***) **pixie features** like the super pointy chins and use maybe a different font. Daniella likes a "lipstick" font or something a bit rock n roll

Is the adjective "pixie" defined at my dictionary?

> :  playfully mischievous :  given to or marked by pranks :  puckish, impish, roguish
>   *pixie humor;
>   a pixie grin*

I got this sentence from my country's Q&A site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [pixie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixie) is a fairy-like creature found in Cornish folklore.

> A **pixie** (also pixy, pixi, pizkie, piskie and pigsie as it is sometimes known in Cornwall) is a mythical creature of folklore. Pixies are considered to be particularly concentrated in the high moorland areas around Devon and Cornwall, suggesting some Celtic origin for the belief and name.
>
> In traditional regional lore, pixies are generally benign, mischievous, short of stature and attractively childlike; they are fond of dancing and gather outdoors in huge numbers to dance or sometimes wrestle, through the night, demonstrating parallels with the Cornish plen-an-gwary and Breton Fest Noz (Cornish: troyl) folk celebrations originating in the medieval period. In modern times they are usually depicted with pointed ears, and often wearing a green outfit and pointed hat although traditional stories describe them wearing dirty ragged bundles of rags which they happily discard for gifts of new clothes. Sometimes their eyes are described as being pointed upwards at the temple ends. These, however, are Victorian era conventions and not part of the older mythology.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pixie) defines them as:

> a supernatural being in folklore and children's stories, typically portrayed as small and humanlike in form, with pointed ears and a pointed hat.

Pixie ears are ears that resemble those of legendary fairies: pointed or tapered at the end. Here is an example from Google Images:

[image]

Your sentence in question also makes similar references:

> pixie features like the super pointy chins

Pixie features: basically features that invoke the image of a fairy.

Comment: ah, your answer is exactly same with the answer by our Q&A's (English) "category master"'s. Thank you!.